# Concept for a grails app

Tags: grails, gsp

I am working on a Grails project, its an accounting project. We have multiple clients and they can have multiple types of accounts. I have to create the 'create' page for client, there should be a way to add multiple types of account to the client.

So I was thinking of making a drop-down list with account types and few text boxes to enter account name and other info about account. Also, as a client can have multiple accounts, so I want to create a 'add' button, when clicked it would display a new row to add a new client. I have done this kind of UI before using javascript but in this case, as there is a drop-down list and other components, I think it would be very hard and may not work.

I was thinking of creating a partial view which would render each time user clicked the 'add' button with additional row, problem with this would be during validation errors, edit page and i would also have to pass all values each time user clicks 'add' button.

Is there any other for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the template approach you must use ajax if you don't want to carry on the params that the user has already set.

It is possible to make new drop-down lists appear (or any group of elements inside a `<div>`) when a user clicks a button, since Grails already comes with jQuery you might want to take a look at the `.clone()` method.
The problem with the two listed approeaches is that it will be possible to have duplicates.

Now, another option is to use checkboxes, so you can *check* just the type of account you want.

But to be honest it does seems a bit odd or even inapropiate to let the user choose the type of account he wants with such freedom.

Comment: thanks for the response.
The create and edit pages are for admin user, they want to have that kind of flexibility.
And regarding the .clone(), what would happen to the id and names for elements? Coz i will have to save the values in the textboxes and dropdown list.

Comment: For an example of using .clone() see the LookupTable code (view & controller, especially lookuptable.js) for http://maflt.org/products/Ibidem.

Comment: @Pratik if you plan on using clone(), you will have to change the ids yourself, wich is really easy, just append a number to the original element id. The name can be the same and when the form is sumbitted it will be recieved by the controller as a list. But really, if the _add_ button is just going to create a dropdown list identical to another, maybe you should consider the checkbox approach.